# Insert an object into NSMutable array and shift element one position ahead iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I want to insert an object (say 1.5) into NSMutableArray (say array with content: 1,2,3,4) between 1 and 2. The resultant array would be one element greater (say 1,1.5,2,3,4).

How can this be acheived in iOS using NSMutableArray?

Comment: Inset and resort after.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know the index to insert at, just use `NSMutableArray`'s `insertObject:atIndex:` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject%3aatIndex%3a)). In your case, you want:

```
[yourMutableArray insertObject:@(1.5) atIndex:1];
```

If you don't know the index, you can do something like [this (copy-pasted because nobody likes broken links)](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/01/array-self-sorting/):

```
@implementation NSMutableArray (SelfSorting)

- (void)insertNumberAtSortedLocation:(NSNumber *)aNumber
{
    NSUInteger count = [self count];

    // if there are no contents yet, simply add it
    if (!count)
    {
        [self addObject:aNumber];
        return;
    }

    NSRange searchRange;
    searchRange.location = 0;
    searchRange.length = count;


    // bubble sort finding of insert point
    do
    {
        NSInteger index = searchRange.location + searchRange.length/2;

        NSNumber *testNumber = [self objectAtIndex:index];

        switch ([aNumber compare:testNumber])
        {
            case NSOrderedAscending:
            {
                //searchRange.length = searchRange.length / 2;
                searchRange.length = index - searchRange.location;
                break;
            }
            case NSOrderedDescending:
            {
                int oldLocation = searchRange.location;
                searchRange.location = index+1;
                searchRange.length = searchRange.length - (searchRange.location - oldLocation);
                break;
            }
            case NSOrderedSame:
            {
                searchRange.length = 0;
                searchRange.location = index;
                break;
            }
        }
    }   while  (searchRange.length&gt;0);

    // insert at found point
    [self insertObject:aNumber atIndex:searchRange.location];
}
```

And then, call:

```
[yourMutableArray insertNumberAtSortedLocation:@(1.5)];
```

Comment: But will this shift the rest of contents appropriately in array?

Comment: Yes. Your array will contain 1,1.5,2,3,4 after the insert. This will **not** replace `2`. You have `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Two lines of code

Just append the item and then sort or sort at usage time, sorting is actually very cheap, **almost** O(n) for non pathological cases.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [@[@1, @2 ,@3 ,@4] mutableCopy];

// Two lines of code:
[a addObject:@(1.5)];
[a sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

NSLog(@"a: %@", a);
```

NSLog oputput:

```
a: (
   1,
   "1.5",
   2,
   3,
   4
)
```

The above should be O(log n)

Or if you don't want the entire array sorted, just insert after the first entry that is less than it:

```
NSUInteger count = [a count];
int index = 0;
while (index < count && [a[index] compare:aNumber] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    index += 1;
}
[a insertObject:aNumber atIndex:index];
```

The above is O(n) as opposed to a binary search which is O(log n) but for most arrays there is not a meaningful time difference.

Answer (score 0):

For the example in your question, you would write `[array insertObject:@(1.5) atIndex:1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray * foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[foo insertObject:<#(id)#> atIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
```